# Scrolling content within a sticky div with hidden overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll, sticky

So, I'm trying to figure out a cool/different way to show full web designs that differs from long static images. My goal is to have a "monitor" graphic stick while an image (full web page) flows inside it as the user scrolls. I sorta solved it by having a position sticky "monitor" graphic with an image flowing under it. I love how it scrolls though the content then pushes the section up after it finishes.

The problem is with the image overflow. I was able to hide the overflow on the top with a border (which i think will work fine in the long run).. but I can't figure out how to hide the overflow at the bottom and still keep the same scrolling behavior it has now.

It would be great to also somehow get rid of the space at the bottom of the "monitor" so it sits right at the bottom of the container. I suppose the functionality would ultimately be like a sticky iframe that can be scrolled outside the frame itself and would then push up after the content reaches its end.

I was able to this far, but really having an issue hiding the overflow at the bottom of the div while still maintaining the scroll behavior.

EXAMPLE >> https://codepen.io/cjcort/pen/NWKryVa

Thanks in advance!

```
<style>
body {
    margin:0px;
}

.container-1 {
    background-color:grey;
}

.container-2 {
    background-color:lightblue;
}

.parent {
    width:50%;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:100px 0px;
}

.sticky-monitor {
    text-align: center;
    z-index:1
}

.grey {
    border-top:70px grey solid;  
}

.blue{
    border-top:70px lightblue solid;
}

.sticky-monitor img {
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:4
}

.image {
    margin-top:-65%;
    text-align:center;
}

.image img {
    width:93%;
    height:1000px !important;
    margin:auto
} 


.is-sticky {
    position: sticky; 
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    top: 0; 
}
</style>



<div class="container-1">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="sticky-monitor is-sticky grey">
            <img src="https://charliecort.com/test/computer.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563468415006-0b70ca8eb306?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-1">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="sticky-monitor is-sticky grey">
            <img src="https://charliecort.com/test/computer.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563468415006-0b70ca8eb306?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `overflow: hidden` and `position: sticky` ruins the sticky effect.
[Dealing with overflow and position: sticky](https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/)

It greatly limits CSS solutions. For now, I can only think in a JavaScript one.
You can calculate the height of the container space below the monitor. This height will be used in a element to hide the escaping image part.

First, create an div in `sticky-monitor`. Let's set `.hide-image` class to it:

```
<div class="sticky-monitor is-sticky grey">
  <img src="http://charliecort.com/test/computer.svg">
  <div class="hide-image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
    transform: translateY(-4px); // to fill the small gap
}
```

Finally, the JavaSript for the height calculation. There will be a base calculation variable whose values will be recalculated only when the window resizes, since during scroll they don't change. The height will be calculated whenever scroll happens:

```
// variables to get elements;
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var monitor = document.querySelector('.container .sticky-monitor');
var hideImageElement = document.querySelector('.hide-image');

// variable for calculation later
var baseForCalc;

window.addEventListener('resize', getValuesImage);
window.addEventListener('scroll', adjustHideImage);

function getValuesImage() {
    baseForCalc = container.offsetHeight + container.offsetTop - monitor.offsetHeight;
    adjustHideImage();
}

function adjustHideImage () {
    hideImageElement.style.height = (baseForCalc - monitor.offsetTop) + 'px';
}

getValuesImage(); // get the values at least once
adjustHideImage(); // apply the values at least once
```

Comment: I figured Javascript would have to play a part. Thanks for this Azametzin, ill give it a shot!

Comment: So, I ran into a bit of a snag with this solution. It works great when there is nothing above the container, but when something is, it adjusts for that height as well leaving a cap at the bottom. Can you think of a fix? 

https://codepen.io/cjcort/pen/qBWrPMV

Comment: I think you should remove `- monitor1.offsetTop` from calculation. Looking better, I don't think it's necessary. Test it on a more complex layout to see if it works well.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It's definitely looking better, but now that I removed `- monitor1.offsetTop`im afraid the hidden element is now covering the containers below. 

https://codepen.io/cjcort/pen/qBWrPMV

Im sorry for all the back and forth, thanks much for your help

Comment: Ok, now I see why it was there. The problem now is the space above the section. You can add `webSection.offsetTop` value to the calculation. But now I'm worried about performance, so wait a minute, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Works perfectly this time! Thanks agian!